# How can I compute a dual norm in R?

Tags: r, optimization, convex

Suppose I have a norm $||x||$. Is there an R function or method that allows me to calculate the dual norm

$$||y||_* = \max_{x} x^Ty : ||x||\leq 1$$

My initial thought is that this falls under a constrained optimisation problem, so I imagine there's some useful packages to solve this, but I haven't been able to formulate how to do this.

Comment: i'm not aware of any such function. usually, the notion of a dual norm is most useful when it corresponds to another simple norm such that we don't have to actually solve the optimization problem numerically. Do you have a specific case in mind? That might help focus this.